# Where to buy ethanol in Canada?

Tags: cooking, canada

I have recently moved from Sweden to Canada.  In Sweden, I always bought ethanol for my trangia ethanol stove at petrol stations.  Where can I buy such ethanol in Canada?  Is it sold at petrol stations, or will I need to visit more speciality stores?  What is the colloquial name?

Comment: I think you will find some at canadian tire (http://www.canadiantire.ca/).

Comment: Canada is a large country, and store inventories can vary greatly. I suggest a reworking of your question to help get some answers. And by the way, Everclear is 100% ethanol, which can be purchased at liquor stores. Denatured alcohol is ethanol with some additives so that it can't be ingested, and can be purchased at most hardware and home improvement stores.

Comment: MEC sell Methyl Alcohol $4.95+tax for 1 litre Weight: 852g http://www.mec.ca/product/1507-052/recochem-1l-methyl-hydrate-stove-fuel/?f=10&q=Methyl%2BAlcohol

Comment: @Mapperz -- Oddly, MEC no longer sells it (even though they do still sell Trangia stoves!)

Comment: CanadianTire have the product (1 litre) [August 2018] http://www.canadiantire.ca/en/pdp/methyl-hydrate-0497127p.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did find ethanol at Canadian Tire (in downtown Toronto).

However, they only had a large bottle (almost 4L), so it's not suitable if one is already on their way; you should still get a smaller bottle and find a place to store the larger container.

Comment: Another possibility in the future is called "Gas Line Anti-freeze" sold by a brand called HEET in many gas stations.  The Yellow bottle is the one.

Comment: @Ryley Do you have a link to such a product?  I would hesitate to pour anti-freeze into my camping stove.

Comment: https://www.goldeagle.com/product/heet-gas-line-antifreeze-water-remover/  The yellow one is methanol.  If you find only the red bottle, it's isopropanol which would work but isn't nearly as good.  I've used the yellow bottle on multiple thru-hikes (months of daily usage).

Answer (score 5):

Ethanol is usually sold as *bio-ethanol* in Canada, although, strictly speaking, it is really *denatured alcohol* (i.e., it has an additive to prevent people from drinking it). While you can get it from Canadian Tire, Home Hardware, Lowes, Rona, Ace Hardware, and Walmart, it is generally more expensive than *methanol*.

Note that *methanol* (aka *methyl hydrate*) burns just as well in alcohol stoves. 
You can get 946ml bottles of methanol from Canadian Tire, Home Depot, Home Hardware, Lowes, Ace Hardware, and Rona.
You can get 500ml bottles of methanol from Canadian Tire, Home Hardware, and Rona.
And, of course, it's cheaper to get 3780ml containers. I recommend getting small bottles to carry on trips and large bottles for refuelling the small ones.

For other names, see [What are the different names for and sources of alcohol for my stove?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/20056/what-are-the-different-names-for-and-sources-of-alcohol-for-my-stove)

Comment: Is that actually pure methanol, or methylated spirits (UK name)/denatured alcohol (US)? Pure methanol is rather toxic, and it's usually added in fairly small quantities to ethanol

Comment: That's not quite right. Methanol!=meths though meths may contain methanol. Wikipedia:*Denatured alcohol, also called methylated spirit (methylated spirits in Australia and New Zealand) or denatured rectified spirit, is ethanol that has additives to make it poisonous, bad tasting, foul smelling or nauseating*. So meths is ethanol-based stove fuel/degreaser. Pure methanol is appreciably toxic by inhalation or skin contact.

Comment: @ChrisH - thanks to your clarification, i re-wrote https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/20056/what-are-the-different-names-for-and-sources-of-alcohol-for-my-stove?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @ChrisH: In Canada, methanol is sold as 99.9% pure, and bio-ethanol is sold with additives.

Comment: Methyl Hydrate is the stuff in Canada - I use it in my alcohol stoves all the time.

Answer (score 3):

I live in British Columbia and I just purchased some denatured alcohol at Ace Hardware in the Lower Mainland. The brand is Klean strip. Ace Hardware does have locations across Canada, hopefully one near you.

Comment: Welcome to The Great Outdoors and thanks for your answer! Make sure to check out our [tour](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how things work on our site. Also, one small remark: Please keep in mind that our users are from all over the world and not everyone understands abbreviations like "BC" - although probably many interested in this question might.

Comment: Strangely, i could not find klean-strip or denatured alcohol at www.ace-canada.ca but i did find ethanol and methanol.

Comment: Mmlaybe they don't advertise it because Canada has restrictions? Or it cannot be shipped? no idea. I just stumbled across it on the shelves while I was in the Cloverdale area (Surrey) store. Two sizes 976 ml and larger.

Answer (score 1):

When I couldn't find a Canadian Tire, I bought "rubbing alcohol" in a pharmacy. Works as well.

Comment: Are you sure? I've heard that it has a dirty flame -- leaves a dirty residue.

Comment: According to Wikipedia rubbing alcohol may be based on isopropanol or ethanol. The former burns dirty. The bottle may or may not be more specific